# Do PS1 games play quietly on a PS2?

Tags: ps2, ps1

I've got a slim silver PS2 and wanted to buy some PS1 games. I've noticed that the PS2 games that come on CDs instead of DVDs (blue disc vs. normal silver) spin loudly — it's like I left a hairdryer in my game cabinet! Just like how CDs spin up noisily in a PC or laptop DVD drive. I always found it an obnoxious design flaw.

Well, my question is: Do you know if PS1 games are like this in the PS2? If so, I'll probably spend the extra few bucks to get a PS1 to catch up on my vintage games.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, you're asking if PS1 CDs are treated differently than PS2 CDs by the system?  (E.g., whether they're spun slower?)

Comment: Yes, I wasn't sure if it needs to spin them up to a fast speed and hence is noisy like the blue discs, or it reads the data at a low speed - don't have one on hand to test myself. Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't recall any PS1 games being particularly noisy in my PS2. Generally the drive speed is slower for PS1 games unless you change the settings in the menu.

Comment: Ah cool you can choose to set the drive speed? I'll check that out. And thx for the confirmation re: noise.

Comment: There are several options you can choose when starting a PS1 game. I think drive speed is one of them. The other, I think, is texture smoothing.